# How to update a user?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

### The goal

Update a user's table consistently.

### The problem

I have to edit the information  of a specific user and I don't know how.

- Firstly, there's a `Users` table on my application that stores all the information of some user.
- Secondly, I can't think in a recursive way to do this. There're multiple columns on the `Users` table and I don't know how to edit just the columns that the user requested. **Any idea?**

### What I really want?

I'm not executing any query through C#. Everything that I need from database came via a Stored Procedure. (Except the basics like `.Select()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, etc.). In other words, I need two things:

1. A (MySQL) recursive query syntax idea;
2. I need a C# method to invoke my stored procedure like this:

---

```
User user = new User("chiefmaster@test.com"); // The target of the update.
UpdateUser
    (user.Email => "masterchief@test.com", // the old is "chiefmaster@test.com"
     user.Nickname => "MasterChief" // the old is "ChiefMaster");
```

As you can see, I'm updating the `Email` and the `Nickname` of a specific user — this should not affect the other user's information.

Can you give me  ideas or a way to follow?

Comment: What database are you using MySql?

Comment: `user.Email => "masterchief@test.com"` this syntax is illegal.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand why can't you use `update Users set Email = 'masterchief@test.com', Nickname = 'MasterChief' where Email = 'chiefmaster@test.com`?

Comment: @RePierre the number of fields that are updated can be different each time, in the next run the user could modify his ADRESS but neither the email nor the nickname

Comment: You could just send in the full info of the updated object and write changes. Failing that, for unchanged values, send a default value (empty string, 0, etc) which your stored proc ignores. This seems quite routine work so I assume I'm missing something though.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways of solving this, what have you tried? You can for example use an ORM, which handles this for you.

You can also manually implement dirty flags per property and save only the changed properties.

Or you can create a method `UpdateUserEmailAndNickname(User user, string newEmail, string newNickname)`.

Answer (score 1):

I propose that you create a Stored Procedure that when recieves and empty parameter '' it keeps the previous values

```
create procedure UpdateUser(IN idUpdate INT, IN newEmail varchar(30), IN newNick varchar(30))
begin

DECLARE prevEmail varchar(30);
DECLARE prevNick varchar(30);

DECLARE updEmail varchar(30);
DECLARE updNick varchar(30);

select email into prevEmail, nick into prevNick 
from USERS 
where id = idUpdate

if(newEmail = '')
    set updEmail = prevEmail
else
    set updEmail = newEmail

if(newNick = '')
    set updNick = prevNick
else
    set updNick = newNick

update USERS 
set email = updEmail, nick = updNick
where id = idUpdate;

end;
```

When you call this procedure you need to pass all the paremeters, but when you detect that a column was not updated just pass it as an empty string(or null value adjusting the store procedure)

Of course you need to add more parameters as needed and declare more variables and adjust this example

Comment: Now try to set a nullable field to null.

Comment: @CodeCaster as my answer say it needs adjustments, another aproach is that when editing a user is first loadad and shown with the exisinting values and after is edited all the fields are sent, which is a combinations of the ones that where edited with the ones that already existed